# Como verificar o tipo dos elementos de uma lista em Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variáveis, lista

Tenho uma lista de dados, e preciso verificar se todos os elementos são inteiros ou *string*, ou qualquer outro tipo de dado. É possível verificar todos os elementos ou precisa ser um por um?

Por exemplo:

```
Lista = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,"7"]
```

Preciso de uma função que me informe se todos eles são inteiros ou não.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Poderia fazer isto:

```
all(isinstance(n, int) for n in lista)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Collection/VerifyTypes.py).

Já existe algo pronto ([`isinstance()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) e [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all)).

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8964208/221800).

Comment: Obrigado por responder prontamente. Funcionou, existe algum caso em que essa função não possa ou não deva ser utilizada?

Comment: Sempre tem, mas no geral não tem problema. Dará problema em caso que não é dela, mas algo colateral, por isso teria que ver o contexto.

Comment: Estou fazendo uma função para calcular o checksum de um pacote de dados para ser enviado de forma serial. Então verifico o tamanho do buffer e se todos os dados são inteiros, para então poder calcular o checksum e preparar os dados para serem enviados.

Comment: No caso de um checksum, `isinstance(dado, int)` pode não ser uma boa - já que você não precisa apenas de  inteiros - precisa de inteiros de 0 a 255 sem sinal, cada um represenando um byte. Nesse caso, vocẽ pode simplesmente tentar transformar sua lista em um objeto do tipo `bytes` ou `bytearray` - se um dos valores estiver fora da faixa, isso vai causar um erro. : `sum(bytes(meus_dados))`